I have 40 rows in a SQL database. I want to show 15 rows per page. But when I run the following code, it just print top 15 rows again and again
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (itemCounter < itemPerPage)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cCode"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(60, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cName"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cShortAddress"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(310, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cPhone"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(580, Ypos));

        Ypos = Ypos + 22;
        itemCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        Ypos = 182;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
}
rdr.Close();

Please help me so that I can control the loop.
I have tried another loop. In for loop similar problem occurs. I want to print 0 to 14 index data in one page and 15 to 29 index data in another page and so on.
Please know me if any way to print the invoice by for loop. Thank you.
for (i = itenCounter; i < totalItem; i++)
{
    rdr.Read();

    if (itemCounter < itemPerPage)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cCode"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(60, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cName"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cShortAddress"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(310, Ypos));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cPhone"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(580, Ypos));

        Ypos = Ypos + 22;
        itemCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        Ypos = 182;
        e.HasMorePages= true;
    }
}

itenCounter = itenCounter + itemPerPage;


if (itemCounter < itemPerPage) When this condition is false, the code executes the else block, which does not draw anything.

That snippet needs some optimization;: for one thing you are creating a lot of identical Font objects and disposing of none of them.  Your app is going to leak.  Also there are many, many good answers already here on printing multiple pages.  Feel free to consult them.

Here is the sample to print 15 rows per page from a SQL database using a PrintDocument in a Windows Forms application.
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
           Button printButton = new Button
           {
               Text = "Print",
               Location = new Point(120, 10)
           };
           printButton.Click += PrintButton_Click;
           Controls.Add(printButton);
       }
       private PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
      
       private SqlDataReader rdr;
       private int itemCounter = 0;
       private int itemsPerPage = 15;
       private int totalItemCount = 40; 
       private int currentPageIndex = 0;
       private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          
           StartPrint();
       }
       private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
       {
           if (rdr == null)
           {
               e.HasMorePages = false;
               return;
           }

           int startIndex = currentPageIndex * itemsPerPage;
           int Ypos = 182; 

           while (itemCounter < startIndex + itemsPerPage && itemCounter < totalItemCount)
           {
               if (rdr.Read())
               {
                  
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cCode"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(60, Ypos));
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cName"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, Ypos));
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cShortAddress"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(310, Ypos));
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(rdr["cPhone"].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(580, Ypos));

                   Ypos += 22; 
                   itemCounter++;
               }
           }
          
           if (itemCounter < totalItemCount)
           {
               e.HasMorePages = true; 
               currentPageIndex++; 
           }
           else
           {
               e.HasMorePages = false; 
               ResetCounters(); 
           }
       }

       private void ResetCounters()
       {
           itemCounter = 0;
           currentPageIndex = 0;
       }

       private void StartPrint()
       {
          
           using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
           {
               conn.Open();
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT cCode, cName, cShortAddress, cPhone FROM [dbo].[TestTable]", conn))
               {
                   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   printDocument.Print();
               }
           }
       }
     

   }


